# WSL ubuntu won't reinstall

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

More WSL than Ubuntu issue.
Following a post on https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8260#issuecomment-1095332420, but in summary, deleted a wsl1 ubuntu repo then next day my wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 wouldn't boot. Unregistered the latter too, but now I can't install either. Just to be clear, it's the 20.04 install that I want.

```
PS C:\Users\jo> wsl --install -d Ubuntu
Ubuntu is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
PS C:\Users\jo> wsl --install -d Ubuntu-20.04
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is already installed.
Launching Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...
PS C:\Users\jo> wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop (Default)
docker-desktop-data
PS C:\Users\jo> ubuntu
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x800706d9
Error: 0x800706d9 There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but this may help others in the same situation.

The reinstall problem lies in the "application" that is installed with the distro, when you install a Linux distro in WSL it's installed also as an application. When you delete the distro from WSL it does NOT uninstall that app so you need to manually uninstall it from apps and features. Search for "Ubuntu" in the installed apps and uninstall it, once uninstalled you will be able to install Ubuntu again from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a little different than the way I understood the comment on Github.

Let's start with "normal" troubleshooting on that error.

- From [Troubleshooting Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting), it mentions that that particular error can occur in WSL2 when Internet Connection Sharing [(ICS) is disabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#wsl-2-errors-when-ics-is-disabled).  Is there any chance that is the case?
- Related, and also easy to check and fix if it's the case, [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880768/11810933) mentions that the same error was received when the `Host Network Service` was disabled.  Check it through the *Services* snap-in.
- I'm hopeful that one of those two items takes care of it, but if not, there are a few other suggestions in [this Github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4403) including removing any Hyper-V features, the Virtual Machine Platform, etc.  Then reinstall them after a reboot.  This didn't seem to work for most people, however, just as a heads-up.

Comment: Well it started with the problems in that thread! ICS & Host Network Service are running. The things in that github thread seem really unlikely to be issues when this system was perfectly fine before and I'm not keen to start playing around with them.

Comment: @FokeyJoe Okay, how about the other items I mentioned in the Github thread?  I'm assuming there was no existing `..\Packages\CanonicalGroup...Ubuntu..\` directory?

Comment: Yeah, they are there. I've tried renaming them, it still thinks 20.04 is there and restores the folder each time. I think I just want to clear it all out and start again from scratch.

Comment: @FokeyJoe Still noodling on this, but a question in the meantime.  Are your apps in the Microsoft Store set to auto-update?  Or do you need to manually update?

Comment: I think they were on manual update, but I have since uninstalled WSL and it auto-reinstalled on a windows update. AFAICT, it was all the latest version anyway. I was wondering whether I've messed up and switched between admin user and normal user when running the commands. But now I've got that stupid start menu disappearing bug and can't easily get back to an admin powershell to try that! Windows is not my fave OS at this moment in time!!